# Make a query to select rows in which data is repeated in mirror mode

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have the following tables:

| Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 20 |
| 97 | 42 |
| 20 | 12 |
| 45 | 87 |
| 54 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 |
| 98 | 27 |
| 34 | 54 |

How could I select the rows in which data is repeated in mirror mode?
In this example the awnser would be the selection of rows 1,3,5 and 8 as is in row 1 we can see 12-20 and in row 3 20-12 and 54-34 is in row 5 and 34-54 is in row 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t.`Table 1`
       ,t.`Table 2`
from    t join t t2 on   t.`Table 1` = t2.`Table 2` and t.`Table 2` = t2.`Table 1`
```

| Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 12 |
| 12 | 20 |
| 34 | 54 |
| 54 | 34 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9zXiiRgY)